Django не видит файлы в папке static
Собственно в первый раз работаю на Джанго, делаю сайт с аниме-сериалами и столкнулся с проблемой, джанго не видит файлы в папке статик. 
urls;
    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

settings:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/practice/static/',

в html все пути указаны правильно, в консоли даже пишет, что не может найти именно файлы в этой папке.

Во-первых, раздачей файлов должен заниматься не Django, а веб-сервер, и делать вот это вот всё вообще не надо. Во-вторых, раз уж вы это всё сделали и указали раздачу файлов из settings.STATIC_ROOT, то логичный вопрос — а путь-то там правильный прописан?

В общем там дело было в том, что у меня файлы искались не в статике, который для дебага, а в основной папке статик для сервера. Как сделать по-другому я инфы не нашёл, так что просто скопировал всё из первого во второй

Решил вопрос: Переместил файлы из templates/static в main (папка проекта)/static
